# Did Jethro convert? Before or after Matan Torah?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, parashas-yisro, kabbalat-hatorah, yisro--the-man

Did Jethro convert? And, was it before or after the Torah was given?  I heard a few things this past shabbat, but I would like to see if we can compile all of the midrashic and aggadic opinions.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13979

Comment: This question would be improved if you would add to it whatever you know about the topic, on which you're basing your question. (For example, any reasons you have for thinking he converted (and when) or didn't.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=) he converted.

According to the [Even Ezra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=) he converted after Matan Torah. The [Ramban](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=) and [Abarbanel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19156&st=&pgnum=266) say prior to Matan Torah. The [Ramban](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=263) says that he returned home afterwards to convert his family.

Comment: Can you please provide on which Pasuk?

Comment: I don't see any of these *meforshim* saying whether or not Yisro converted at all. They are merely discussing when Yisro came to visit Moshe.

Comment: True that Rashi (quoting Sifri) believes Yisro converted. But can you please point to where Ibn Ezra, Ramban and Abarbanel say that he did?

Comment: If you look a few pages further http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=263 the Ramban says that he went back home to convert his family also. I think that the Mefarshim all agree that Yisro converted and you would have to show me that Yisro did not convert in order to prove so.

Comment: Thank you for that Ramban. It does very much imply that Yisro converted, although he doesn't seem to specify that it was prior to Matan Torah as you claim. Ibn Ezra, though, I cannot find where he says anything on the subject. Re Abarbanel: I found his explicit statement that Yisro converted in Parshas B'haalos'cha [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14388&st=&pgnum=41), although he seems to imply that it was *after* Matan Torah.

Comment: Also, I disagree that the burden of proof is necessarily on the position that Yisro did not convert. If anything, the opposite is true, for he left the Jews in the desert to return to his own homeland instead of joining them into E"Y, which seems like a preposterous act if he was indeed Jewish.

Comment: @jake: is it that straightforward that this is what he did, though? It does mention in Ex. 18:27 that Yisro left, but in Num. 10:29ff it just ends with Moshe's plea to him to stay, perhaps indicating that he indeed did so. Which would mean that these two accounts are describing two different visits, which I believe some mefarshim say explicitly (will have to look for sources).

Comment: @Alex, True. Some (like the Ramban linked above) say like you suggest. Others (like Abarbanel that I linked to) say that it was one long visit after which he left even though Moshe pleaded with him not to. (Then the "Moshe sent him back home" from Parshas Yisro would be referring to what happened a couple of years later.) Personally, I would put the burden of proof on both sides of this argument (whether Yisro converted).