# Was Yisro called by his 7 names?

Tags: names, parashas-yisro

Rashi to [Shemos 18:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.18.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.18.1&lang2=bi) lists 7 names that Yisro had. Was he called by all these names? For example if he would've gotten an Aliyah would he be called up by all 7 names?
([Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/did-jethro-convert-before-or-after-matan-torah) is a source that Yisro converted.)